# How to stop VB.Net FixedToolWindows getting maximized

Tags: vb.net

I have an application with several FixedToolWindow forms and one Sizable window form inside MDIParent form which runs maximized. If i run FixedToolWindows while Sizable window is unloaded, FixedToolWindows runs with correct sizes.

But if I try to run a FixedToolWindow while the Sizable window running in maximized mode, all the FixedToolWindows gets maximized too.

Following is the code, i use to load forms,

```
    If Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of frmFrontEndLED).Any Then
        MessageBox.Show("Already opened")
    Else
        Dim frmFendLED As New frmFrontEndLED()
        'Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
        frmFendLED.MdiParent = Me
        'Display the New form.
        frmFendLED.TopMost = True
        frmFendLED.Show()
    End If
```

What am i doing wrong?. How can i correct this?

Comment: If you want to make the FixedToolWindow form not maximized, do not make it an MDI child. The children of an MDI Container form must have all forms maximized or none.

Comment: Moreover, if you're starting a new project, I would say consider using a tabbed design instead. MDI applications have been absolute for years as they don't provide good user experience.

Comment: Thanks for the advice

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed, do you mean "obsolete" rather than "absolute"?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes, autocorrect kicked in and I only noticed it after the 5-minutes grace period when the OP replied. Thanks for pointing it out tho!